# Schedule command to run once at specific time, and re-schedule it to the later time if the machine was powered off

Tags: scheduling

`at 10:00` will schedule the command to run at the next occurrence of 10:00. If the machine was powered off at 10:00, `at` will run the command as soon as possible on the next power on

Is there any way to instead re-schedule the command to the later occurrence of 10:00? Any command/package will do

Comment: Another command: `anacron`.